# Duplicate shows as "on hold" in favourite list

Tags: bug, exact-duplicates, bookmarks

Today, I favourited [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1102272/43351) on my phone in order to hunt for a duplicate later. After the question was closed as a duplicate, I saw the following in my favourites list:

[image: Screenshot of situation]

As you can see, it is not listed as `[duplicate]`, but as `[on hold]`.

Comment: [Related on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237846/favorite-questions-are-shown-with-closed-or-on-hold-instead-of-duplicate)